# How to recenter origins of objects on one axis

Tags: objects, origin

I want to use "Origin to Geometry" on multiple objects but only move the objects' origins on one axis. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Bounding box center**

IIRC center to geometry is also the same as bounding box center.

Test script, finds the bounding box center `cog` and only translates the z component.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

bbox = [Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box]
cog = sum(bbox, Vector()) / 8

me.transform(Matrix.Translation((0, 0, -cog.z)))
```

Changing last line to

```
me.transform(Matrix.Translation(-cog))
```

will move origin to center of bounding box.